# How do I use arguments instead of a list?

Tags: scheme

I have it like this `(sigma (list 1 2 3 2 1))` and I need it like this `(sigma 1 2 3 2 1)`. I think I need a function to convert it or rewrite it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (sigma . args)
  ...)
```

That's the syntax for having a variable number of arguments, now you can call it like this:

```
(sigma 1 2 3 2 1)
```

And inside your procedure, treat `args` as a list of arguments to do whatever you need with them.

Comment: @user3522238 Did this post solve your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left. Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).